# mariadb takes too much load though having sufficient RAM

Tags: mysql, mysqltuner, mariadb-10.3

I am facing more CPU usage for my app server. Server configuration is as below.

```
1> CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 v4 @ 2.20GHz 8 core
2> RAM: 32 GB
3> 600 GB SSD NVRAM
4> Mariadb version 10.3.17. 
5> OS: Debian 9
```

I have run mysql tuning script to optimize server performance and add some parameter in my.cnf. But yet it's not creating big impact.

I can see that RAM used very less compare to CPU. How can I balance in both and improve server performance?

Here is my tuner script output [tunner](https://pastebin.com/RhVMcZ48).
Here is current my.cnf output on [my.cnf](https://pastebin.com/k03qa9n4)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by it takes too much load? Depending on what you are doing it will not be possible to balance cpu and ram usage

Comment: Have things changed recently? Did you change hardware? Upgrade software? Does this happen at particular times of the day/week/month? Are you running an OLTP or OLAP system (or both simultaneously). Do you have long-running reports which kick in at certain times of the day or night? Are managers allowed run reports when they feel like it?

Comment: There are many many things which could be going on. Have you looked at any of the performance_schema tables when things are going wrong? (and when they're going right)? Do you have any other systems running on these machines? Do you have the output from sysstat or similar going back over a significant period of time?

Comment: High CPU (load) is a symptom of poor indexes and/or poorly formulated queries.  Let's see the slow queries so we can help you make them run faster.

Comment: @JoeW I mean my CPU load average goes high till 15 - 20%. And RAM is just 5 GB used from 32 GB.

Comment: @Vérace It's one call center application, which has live real time report functions.

Comment: What do you mean it goes high? As long as cpu isn't maxing out is there really a problem?

Comment: @JoeW You are taking my comment in other way. It's not like maxing out but actually it's using out of box. For your query, CPU usage goes upto 500% for mysql service. 15-20% is as per htop command which indicates load everage and it could ideally 3-5% for better performance.

Comment: OK - so you've answered one of my questions - it's a combination of OLTP and OLAP. But you haven't answered any of my stuff about when did this start occurring? At least give us the output of `w` when things are "bad" (and good) - i.e. you load average instead of just saying `goes high till 15 - 20%` which is meaningless - load average is an average of the number of threads running. You say CPU is going to 15 - 20% - grand - your system isn't swamped! How are your user response times? Your report generation times? **Critically**, you don't appear to have metrics from before this.

Comment: Why exactly is that a problem though? From what it sounds like you are not really taxing your system at all.

Answer (score 0):

With your limited information posted, suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
max_connections=512  # from 2000 because max_used_connections only 213
join_buffer_size=256K  # from 20M to reduce RAM required per connection
read_buffer_size=256K  # from 2M to reduce RAM required per connection
read_rnd_buffer_size=128K  # from 8M to reduce RAM required per connection
```

These changes will significantly reduce your CPU busy and provide better performance.

Comment: @Kavin-Chauhan AND with your SSD being used, innodb_io_capacity=1900 # from 200 to allow higher IOPS to your SSD. These 5 suggestions are just the tip of the iceberg. There are many more positive changes that could be made to your my.cnf

Comment: @Kavin-Chauhan Have you tried any of the suggestions?  Please provide positive/negative results comment.

Comment: @kavin-chauhan Have you tried the suggestions of Jan 3, 2020?  Please Add Comment on positive or negative results.